# ALB-Nginx-Fargate Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I have an ALB that sits in front of NGINX. The nginx conf has 9 different server conf each listening on different ports. I'm using Fargate for deploying my cluster using the service discovery.

Now to route my traffic via `ALB -> Nginx -> Django-uwsgi APP`, I added 9 different Target Groups and 9 Listener Ports to ALB, each listener port being associated with one of the target group.

Please note that my ALB does not communicate directly with App, it routes via Nginx. Hence, I've not declared any **load balancer** while configuring my Fargate **APP** service. The load balancer is only declared while configuring **NGINX** fargate service.

Now while configuring load balancer for Nginx fargate service, I can only add upto 5 Target Groups. This means my nginx conf will be able to serve only 5 server conf, target group of whose has been configured while configuring the service.

**How do I configure my rest of the service via the same nginx config?**

I;ve few solutions in my mind:-

1) I deploy 2 nginx services, nginx1 and nginx2, each having 5 target groups each. This solution has cost and operational issues. Cost because there will be `N` nginx services `5N` server conf. Operationally because I have to maintain different nginx files.

2) Target group routes the traffic to IP (in this case nginx service IP). So, whenever I deploy my nginx fargate service, I manually update the Private IP in each of the remaining target groups which were not configured in the service. However, this will result in a problem that whenever my container goes down and Fargate tries to maintain my desired count, my Private IP will be changed without me knowing. This would result in the downtime of the remaining services.

Comment: Do you have any level of support? Because a simpler and ideal solution would be to request AWS to increase your TG limit from 5 to whatever you want - they're a great company and usually listen to their customers.

Comment: Well, I went with the FQDN approach instead of different ports. Now all my services run on same port but with different DNS.